# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express decreasing memory usage

Tags: sql-server-2008-express

I have a virtual machine running windows 2008 standard R2 sp1 and Forefront TMG 2010. TMG 2010 also installs SQL Server 2008 Express for logging activities. According to perfmon SQL Server Express is using about 1 gb of ram. I have tried to decrease buffer pool max memory usage to 100mb (below code), restarted sql process but sometime later it goes up again about 1gb memory usage. SQL is just used for logging TMG activities and not critical so I want to decrease memory footprint of total SQL usage. If it is possible with Microsoft implementation.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)', 100
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
```